# How to get variables from different classes?

Tags: java, class, variables, java.util.scanner, external-methods

So i'm working on this project and i'm having trouble moving variables from one class to the other. The goal of this tiny software is to have the user input 2 pieces of information, one's a string and the other is an int. I also have 2 classes, one to retrieve the information and the other one to calculate it. 
This is the first class called Software:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Software
{
public Scanner softwareName;
public Scanner devicesAmount;


public Software()
{
    devicesAmount = new Scanner(System.in);
    softwareName = new Scanner(System.in);
}

/**
*Gets the information from the user to later on process
*/
public void InfoGet()
{
    Devices findDevices= new Devices();
    Devices findNumber= new Devices();

    String softwareName;
    int devicesAmount;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Software License Calculator");
    System.out.println("Please type in the name of the Software:");

    softwareName = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Please type in the number of devices that have the software:");
    devicesAmount=sc.nextInt();

    findDevices.Calculations(devicesAmount);
    findNumber.getNewDevices();

    sc.close();
    System.out.println(softwareName+ " & "+ findNumber);
   }
}
```

And here's the second class called Devices:

```
public class Devices
{
public int NewDevices;
public String softwareName;

   /**
    * Gets number of Devices to preform the calculations of removing 1000 users
    */
    public static void Devices()
    {
    Software getDevices= new Software();
    getDevices.InfoGet();
    }

    public void Calculations(int devicesAmount){
    if (devicesAmount>=1000){
        NewDevices= devicesAmount - 1000;
    }
    else{
        NewDevices=devicesAmount;
    }
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dunno why I post as user when I'm on my movil device, but to the point:

First of all in the class *Software* you have 2 objects "Device", following the MVC arquitecture you should only declare 1 controller object for the view class, to start I recommend you to only declare 1 Device for Software class, like this and we're gonna make the variables protected just cause they should be private or protected to respect the encapsulation:

```
public class Software {

  protected Devices devices;
  protected Scanner softwareName;
  protected Scanner devicesAmount;
... }
```

I recommend you to do the same for the Devices class variables.

Then we're gonna build a proper constructor for Devices class so we can move the values through classes:

```
public Devices (String softwareName) {
  this.softwareName = softwareName;
  this.newDevices = 0;
}
```

So we can have this values at the Devices class. Then we need to add the getter for *newDevices* and adding the *toString* method to the Devices class so you can print the object.

```
public int getNewDevices() {
  return newDevices;
}

public String toString() {
  return softwareName + " & " + newDevices;
}
```

Then we're gonna move some stuff at the Software *InfoGet* method to build de devices correctly and printing it.

```
public void InfoGet() {
String softwareName;
int devicesAmount;

Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Welcome to the Software License Calculator");
System.out.println("Please type in the name of the Software:");

softwareName = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("");

System.out.println("Please type in the number of devices that have the software:");
devicesAmount=sc.nextInt();

devices = new Devices(softwareName); // So we initialize the object.
devices.Calculations(devicesAmount);

sc.close();
System.out.println(devices.toString()); // Here we just call the toString() method we build to print the values.
}
```

We didn't use the *getNewDevices()* method, but building getters and setters for controller classes is a good practice in general ;).

Comment: The devicesAmount variable wasn't sent to the Devices class, because when I reached the end while compiling.. it printed out the software name and the number 0, even though i entered 1500

Comment: Sorry! My mistake at the line: devices.Calculations();, you should send the devicesAmount as a parameter, like this devices.Calculations(devicesAmount);

Comment: Nice!! It was a pleasure to help you!

Comment: There's another class that i want to add called Prices, and this time it only affects the Devices Class.. do you mind helping me out?

Comment: is there a way that i can contact you directly?

Comment: mail me:
ale.crts1996@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to read about MVC (model-view-controller) if you wanna build your proyect in a "standar" way.

To solve your problem you can add to each class the getters and setters for each variable you need to move so you can move values between classes.

Like this for setters:

```
public void setValue(Object value) {
  this.value = value;
}
```

And this for getters:

```
public Object getValue() {
  return this.value;
}
```

Comment: I think I typed it up wrong:    `    findDevices.Calculations(devices2);
                            findNumber.getNewDevices();
        
               sc.close();
        System.out.println(software+ " & "+ findNumber);
    }
    
    public Object getValue() {
     return this.value;
    }
    ` and in the Devices class, i made the setter and initialized NewDevices as the value.

Comment: is there any way that I may contact you directly?

Comment: Lets try to solve it here, give me a sec I'm trying to give you were you should place each setter or getter in order to make it work ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's very confusing between Scanner, Device, Software, classes and objects with the same name upper or lower cases.

I should recommend to rename you classes and variable clearly.

Some further advices:

- why keeping Scanner as variables ? It's not data, it media to get it.
- why note keeping data ? like softwareName (Scanner AND String).

I would

- add two variables (softwarename and amount), private
- keep them
- add methods to Set and Get

Comment: fixed them, hopefully this will help

Answer (score -1):

`Calculations()` (and others) won't compile. Probably you need to add an argument to that method and you are done (?):

```
 public void Calculations(int devices2){
 ...
```

Comment: it didnt work, i only got this as an output:                                                             Welcome to the Software License Calculator
Please type in the name of the Software:
Microsoft

Please type in the number of devices that have the software:
1500
Microsoft & Devices@5428c92f

Comment: I don't know why the "Microsoft & Devices@5428c92f" appeared, and that's the: `System.out.println(software+ " & "+ findNumber);`